# HW RAID1 or ZFS mirror

Tags: raid, unix, solaris, zfs

Which is best ?

Mirroring 2 internal disks with HW raid and then putting ZFS filesystem on top

or

Using the 2 internal disks without HW Raid and creating a ZFS mirror with the 2 disks.

I've read that to get the full benifits of ZFS it needs at least 2 disks to use its error correction and prediction features fully.

Its a question of ZFS ontop of HW RAID , or just ZFS , not HW vs ZFS . Performance is not my issue.

Comment: What kind of hardware RAID?

Comment: It was the internal RAID card on an Oracle X4470. RAID 1 with the two internal disks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ZFS works optimally if it knows as much as possible about the underlying physical disk structure. A hardware RAID 1 will present a single volume to the OS which ZFS will then treat as a single disk. You'll therefore miss out on the benefits of error correction / fault detection / checksumming etc.

There's another benefit to using ZFS over HW RAID - if your hardware dies, be it the motherboard, RAID card, CPU etc, you can pull the disks and use them in any other system that is running ZFS, and the entire filesystem is readable. If you use HW RAID, you may have a dependency on that specific RAID card, so if it fails you might need to find a similar model before you can read the disks again. You can mitigate this by having dual RAID cards, but this usually starts to become expensive and complex.

In my experience, for the majority of use-cases that I've used a mirrored disk configuration, the performance difference between ZFS and HW RAID wasn't great. If performance is your #1 priority, HW RAID will offer the best solution. In all other cases, I believe ZFS is the better choice.

Comment: How can having to write data twice immediately over the bus come close to the performance of writing once immediately to RAM, regardless of how much RAM and CPU you've got?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - both HW RAID and ZFS will do write caching...? In fact, ZFS lets you specify an entire set of disks as write cache devices if you want to.

Comment: When you write cache in main RAM you lose the data if the machine dies, and write caching to a single disk means you lose the data if that disk dies.  Hardly comparable to battery-backed cache.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. True, battery-backed caches can provide significant benefit in the HW RAID space. I guess ZFS's counter to that would be to use a physical disk as a ZIL rather than RAM. If the machine dies, you can playback the write cache because it's on a persistent disk.

Comment: And if the disk dies, you're *still* up the creek, and wasn't the whole point of running RAID because disks are unreliable?

Comment: So you mirror the ZIL disk?

Comment: And now you're back to where we started, making two writes to disk immediately rather than one write to RAM.

Comment: If write latency is *that* important to you, then use HW RAID. In all other cases, I believe that the advantages of ZFS outweigh those of HW RAID. YMMV. Obviously.

Comment: I'm only questioning your statement that "the performance differences between something like ZFS and hardware RAID1 are becoming negligable".  I agree that ZFS has other benefits.

Comment: You're right, I've badly worded. Will edit. :)

Comment: Hmm I'm still not sure which to use then. The disks would be the root mirrors in a Oracle server. I'd like the ZFS ease of use features, but dont want to compromise on availability. Performance is not an issue for me , resiliance is.  I suppose the only thing I'm worried about is ZFS going wrong if it uses a HW raid device rather than just 2 disks.

Comment: @AndyM: If you want availability then ZFS is a *better* option, hardly any HW RAID solution checks both mirrors when reading let alone adds checksums to written data.

Comment: OK thanks, Im leaning towards the ZFS only option. Some people think its strange not to use the built-in HW RAID on a server, I suppose they dont know the benfits of ZFS :-)

Comment: @growse: You no longer HAVE to mirror the ZIL disks. In the more recent Zpool vers (26+ IIRC) you can safely remove a ZIL disk from a pool. The pool simply reverts to using the pool disks itself for the ZIL.  If you're doing a lot of sync writes then you'd take a performance hit until you replace the ZIL disk.

Comment: @Tim, I think the concern is that if the ZIL device fails, you'll lose whatever's been written to the ZIL but not yet committed to disk. Sure, you can safely remove, but a catastrophic removal is more the worry.

Comment: I had did some more reading and you're 100% right. I totally missed that part in the reading I did. I've had to rethink my own plans for an unmirrored SLOG.

Comment: @growse Isn't it rather like if you lose the ZIL device, then you lose outstanding transaction groups if that loss *coincides* with a system crash? Remember the ZIL in normal operations is write-only; it's only read back on an unclean import. Under normal operations, data is written to ZIL and then committed to storage from ARC (the ZIL not taking part except for disaster recovery).

Answer (score 8):

Although I love ZFS if you're doing a LOT of writing then take into consideration that any software RAID 1/10 will need to send every write twice over the bus and through the controller - meaning you can get into congestion and queue issues.

Comment: This is a good point - from a performance point of view, HW RAID has some significant advantages in certain situations.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have close to 150MiB/s random writes (it's a db server) you're a madman for running it on a single bus. Interface bandwidth is hardly a problem.

Answer (score 2):

ZFS has lots of built in optimizations that work best when used without Raid controllers. On a ZFS Raid1 you get read performance that is usually superior to a hardware Raid, also with RaidZ you can get superior performance to Hardware Raid5
Just take a look at [Anadtech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3963/zfs-building-testing-and-benchmarking/8).

What you absolutely need to take into consideration is how ZFS caches though. You should basically have 4GB of Ram to use it at all, 8GB to get some decent performance, but more is always good. There are lots of cases where more Ram helps with ZFS. The best ways to improve performance though are seperate devices (SSDs) for the ZIL and L2ARC, as those generally tend to be bottlenecking performance. [This](http://blogs.oracle.com/brendan/entry/test) explains the idea behind L2ARC a little.

The principal problem with Hardware Raid here is, that ZFS does, what the Raid Controller does, so when using a Hardware Raid below ZFS, there is a Raid Controller that expects itself and only itself to be doing Queueing, Caching, IO Optimization and so on and there is ZFS on top of it also expecting the same of itself. This has side effects of course and they aren't necessarily pretty and will most likely have negative performance effects due to the way ZFS does I/O Parallelization. Also its predictive "self healing" features will in part be kind of useless that way. Therefor it is specifically recommended that when you use a Raid controller, you should expose the Disks JBOD are as Single-Disk Raid0 devices, so that ZFS can do the housekeeping by itself.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you need to define "best".  I'd expect that a good hardware RAID controller with BBU would provide superior performance, but perhaps performance isn't your primary consideration.

Comment: And my answer is ZFS ontop of HW RAID or just ZFS.

Comment: That is actually a very bad idea. It will basically not be good for ZFSs I/O Parallelization and for exactly this reason its probably not good for the disks either.